# How can we tell the stack frame is currently empty?

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-64, callstack

Suppose inside a loop I want to pop elements from the stack based on some comparison condition (the function will also push some elements to the stack based on some condition). How to avoid popping an empty stack?

If at the beginning of the function, I do

```
push    %rbp
movq %rsp, %rbp
```

And inside the loop, I check if

```
cmpq %rbp, %rsp
je emptyStack
```

is it a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to use the callstack as a stack data-structure, popping until the stack pointer is back at the starting point is normal.  Treat addresses as unsigned: if you want to check for RSP being below RBP, use `cmp`/`jb`.  Or just `cmp/jne` if you're sure RSP can't have gotten *above* RBP.

If you need any stack space for local variables other than your data structure, you'll need a reference point other than `rbp`, or just use `rbp`  as not quite a traditional frame pointer.  e.g. move RSP to make room for locals *before* copying it to RBP.  Having a frame pointer at all is optional anyway.

Having some space above RBP that's still part of your stack data structure might also simplify corner-case handling without risk of stepping on a saved RBP value or return address.  You could just let it go one higher for whatever reason.

e.g.

```
func:
    push  %rbp
    sub   $32, %rsp
    mov   %rsp, %rbp
      # Space from 0(%rbp) to 31(%rbp) can be used for locals separate from your stack data structure

...

    lea    32(%rbp), %rsp       # point RSP at the saved RBP value
    pop    %rbp
    ret
```

Note that an addressing mode of `0(%rbp)` still needs a `disp8`, unlike `0(%rbx)` which can just use no displacement as `(%rbx)`.  So you might choose to use a different register like RBX as the anchor.  Or even a call-clobbered register if this is a leaf function, like RDX or R8.  (If you're not going to use it in any addressing modes, it doesn't matter if you pick one that needs a REX prefix; you'll be using it with 64-bit operand-size when comparing against RSP anyway.  Unless you want to optimize by assuming your stack doesn't cross a 4GB boundary and using `cmp %ecx, %esp` to save 1 byte of code-size.)

```
func:
    lea   -8(%rsp), %rsi        # or just mov, depending what you want.

 ...

    # once RSP is pointing back where it started
    ret
```